# Swagger return response: "can't parse JSON. Raw result:"

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-restcontroller

I am not sure why this is happening. My return statement for `spring boot` rest controller is something like below

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Successfully added");
```

Now on `swagger UI` i see response as below

```
can't parse JSON.  Raw result:

Successfully added
```

why is this happening ?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are returning a string literal instead of a JSON object. I presume your return type would have been `ResponseEntity<String>` but this would not work and you would need to specify an object in the body. You can create a POJO that will hold the message for you, something like this:

```
public class YourResponseClass {
    private String message;
    //Constructors, getter and setter
}
```

Then while returning you need to change the return type to `ResponseEntity<YourResponseClass>` and then return your response:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(new YourResponseClass("Successfully Added."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game but will share my solution to this issue, as it surfaced for me in a Python Flask-based REST backend I was developing recently. You could have NaN values in your JSON, if your issue was similar to mine, albeit in Python.

### My underlying issue

I too was getting "can't parse JSON" on the swagger side. Turns out that Python's standard library `json` import will allow "modern" but not-officially-JSON types, such as "NaN". And doing some calculations with floats and voila...As a strict parser fails with a type such as NaN, it's worth checking that you don't have these in your request JSON response.

#### Solved it with an encoder class

Though not a Java-specific answer, maybe my Python solution can help you solve the issue.

```py
json.dumps(yourdata, cls=NumpyEncoder)
```

Where `NumpyEncoder` is some class that converts `NaN` values to JSON and/or your acceptable specifications. It might be the case that you too can include some encoder class in your code to remove NaN and/or other artifacts.

See my [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903895/5369706) for Python implementation details.

Comment: "NaN" values was exactly my problem. Got rid of them with `df.fillna("")` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing more code and the actual Swagger JSON, but it seems like the JSON has a syntax issue. Run it through a JSON validator to confirm. There are plenty of websites for this if you Google it.

Answer (score -2):

The response type should be `"text/plain" (produces = "MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN")`