# Pandas store dict into json

Tags: python, json

There is a dictionary like this:

```
    thisdict = {'12': [[1, 970000009], [3, 990000547], [9, 900000007]],
          '3': [[2, 970022209], [3, 990000547]],
          '32': [[4, 94042209], [5, 40547]],
          '6575': [[3, 94334009], [2, 923200547], [6, 7807], [7, 98807], [8, 8887]],
...
     }
```

How is it  possible to save this dictionary into a json file?

I tried the below code but it does not work:

```
import json
with open('results.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(thisdict, fp)
```

This is the error in output:

> Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

What is the solution to fix this error?

Comment: Is that really your dictionary? I cannot reproduce the error

Comment: It is a sample of it. It is a large dict.

Comment: Well add a part that causes the error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite your code, change datatype of dictionary and see same error.

```
import json
import numpy as np

thisdict = {'12': [[1, 970000009], [3, 990000547], [9, 900000007]],
            '3': [[2, 970022209], [3, 990000547]],
            '32': [[4, 94042209], [5, 40547]],
            '6575': [[3, 94334009], [2, 923200547], [6, 7807], [7, 98807], [8, 8887]]}
data = list(thisdict.items())
arr = np.array(data)

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(arr, fp)
```

TypeError: Object of type **ndarray** is not JSON serializable

I realize maybe your dictionary have a data type Int64. Please check type of **thisdict**.

**Solution:**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

thisdict = {'12': [[1, 970000009], [3, 990000547], [9, 900000007]],
            '3': [[2, 970022209], [3, 990000547]],
            '32': [[4, 94042209], [5, 40547]],
            '6575': [[3, 94334009], [2, 923200547], [6, 7807], [7, 98807], [8, 8887]],
            }

data = list(thisdict.items())
arr = np.array(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.to_json('result.json')
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code helps to solve it. print(type(thisdict)) command returns <class 'dict'>. There is thisdict[i] = x + y to create this dict. Does it mean that it is an array? If so, an array as you show in your code gives that error. What is the solution if an array like this structure should be stored in a json file?

Comment: Well, you need to add array to DataFrame of pandas, then convert it to json.
```
data = list(thisdict.items())
arr = np.array(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.to_json('result.json')
```
See full code here: https://ideone.com/qRQ5QF

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine, and there's no obvious int64 in the part of the dict you've provided.

Reading between the lines, this looks like numpy data, so your problem is probably not with the dict values, but with the JSON serializer being unable to deal with numpy data types. There are already existing solutions to this problem you can use described here: [Python - TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916422/python-typeerror-object-of-type-int64-is-not-json-serializable)