# How do you change the __repr__ of 0 in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a data pipeline in Pandas, and any given number can be

- Explicitly: `0`
- Missing (`np.nan`)
- Missing, but imputed to have a value of `0`

I'd like to replace the imputed 0's in the table with a value that indicates that they have been imputed. The best I could think of was a "0" where the `repr` is `"-"`

I tried:

```
class MyNaNThatIsLikeZero(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '-'

myNaN = MyNaNThatIsLikeZero()
```

But pandas is converting this to just the float `0.0`

**To clarify, I need this value to behave as 0, so it needs to implement all the dunder methods**

Comment: You must understand, usually and ideally, **there are no `int` or `float` objects in your dataframe at all**. Just add a column with a categorical variable detailing this distinction

Answer (score 0):

> pandas is converting this to just the float 0.0

You can disable that conversion by passing `dtype=object` to the `Dataframe` constructor. See my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907030/13622927