# Saving the weights of a Pytorch .pth model into a .txt or .json

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to save the the weights of a pytorch model into a .txt or .json. When writing it to a .txt,

```
#import torch
model = torch.load("model_path")
string = str(model)
with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as fp:
     fp.write(string)
```

I get a file where not all the weights are saved, i.e there are ellipsis throughout the textfile. I cannot write it to a JSON since the model has tensors, which are not JSON serializable [unless there is a way that I do not know?] How can I save the weights in the .pth file to some format such that no information is lost, and can be easily seen?

Thanks

Comment: I assume what you are doing is actually `str(model.state_dict())`, right? Otherwise no weights would be printed anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `str(model.state_dict())`, it recursively uses `str` method of elements it contains. So the problem is how individual element string representations are build. You should increase the limit of lines printed in individual string representation:

```py
torch.set_printoptions(profile="full")
```

See the difference with this:

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
mobilenet_v2 = models.mobilenet_v2()
torch.set_printoptions(profile="default")
print(mobilenet_v2.state_dict()['features.2.conv.0.0.weight'])
torch.set_printoptions(profile="full")
print(mobilenet_v2.state_dict()['features.2.conv.0.0.weight'])
```

Tensors are currently not JSON serializable.

Comment: A bit late but hopefully this work

Comment: I made a mistake, I was going to add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but hopefully this helps. This is how you store it:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

from json import JSONEncoder
import json

class EncodeTensor(JSONEncoder,Dataset):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, torch.Tensor):
            return obj.cpu().detach().numpy().tolist()
        return super(EncodeTensor, self).default(obj)

with open('torch_weights.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(model.state_dict(), json_file,cls=EncodeTensor)
```

Take into account that the stored values are of type `list` so you have to use `torch.Tensor(list)` when you are going to use the weights.

Comment: What is `NPEncoder`? This? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915246/16157878