# Is there a way to save both PyTorch model architecture and weights as a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, pytorch

I am trying to save a trained model's architecture and weights as JSON files. I understand if only saving the weights, [state_dict() can be stored as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222557/saving-the-weights-of-a-pytorch-pth-model-into-a-txt-or-json).

Or I can save everything with [torch.jit.save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287728/saving-pytorch-model-with-no-access-to-model-class-code), but this gives me a .pth file.

For the project I'm working on, requires everything to be saved as a JSON file. Is there anyway to do so? Assuming the model class will not be available to the user. Should I just write out the architecture as a JSON file and have the user to build it themselves? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom json encoder for the state dict

```py
class TensorEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, torch.Tensor):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

json.dumps(model.state_dict())
```

But why would you force yourself to implement such an obviously bad idea?