# Streamlit web app throws the following error : TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, streamlit

Please consider the code below:

```py
def store_AG(merged_df):
    forecast_df = merged_df
    forecast_df['day(yyyy-mm-dd)'] = pd.to_datetime(forecast_df['day(yyyy-mm-dd)'])
    
    for year in range(forecast_df['day(yyyy-mm-dd)'].dt.year.min(), forecast_df['day(yyyy-mm-dd)'].dt.year.max() + 1):
        for month in range(1, 13):
            month_name = pd.to_datetime(str(month), format='%m').strftime('%B')
            forecast_df[month_name + ' ' + str(year)] = forecast_df['revenue'][
                (forecast_df['day(yyyy-mm-dd)'].dt.month == month) & (forecast_df['day(yyyy-mm-dd)'].dt.year == year)]
    
    st.dataframe(forecast_df)
```

**Context:**
I am trying to do some calculations inside a dataframe and trying to show the dataframe as output on my webapp

The logic is correct and it works just fine on python console but when I run it inside streamlit webapp, it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Even though I have tried changing the datatypes of my datafraemes columns, it still gives the same errorr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916422/python-typeerror-object-of-type-int64-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Or you should try: `forecast_df['revenue'] = forecast_df['revenue'].astype(float)`. If you still get the error. Provide a sample df and also tell use what else you did with data the function produces, because I tested your code and it run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error.  It must be the case that on Streamlit Cloud, some additional level of JSON serialization happens when using `st.dataframe()` that doesn't happen locally.  The solution that worked for me was to just **convert all int columns to floats.**  Not ideal, but it works.

If you were serializing the data yourself, then you could supply additional parameters to `json.dumps()`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916422/python-typeerror-object-of-type-int64-is-not-json-serializable) that one commenter referenced, but since that's happening invisibly as part of the cloud platform itself, that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan appreciate your response