# Python Dataframe object converts to JSON with conditions

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, dataframe

Previously I followed the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762915/how-to-convert-a-python-dataframe-object-to-json) , but then I realized that it's not the same with my case, I'd like to display some values for the same `as_of_dates` and `ID` in the `display_rows` section in the JSON file, I have a dataframe like this:

```
     as_of_date create_date   ID  value_1   count   value_3
0    02/03/2021 02/03/2021  12345   5         2      55
1    02/03/2021 01/03/2021  12345   8         2      55
2    02/03/2021 01/03/2021  34567   9         1      66
3    02/03/2021 02/03/2021  78945   9         1      77
4    03/03/2021 02/03/2021  78945   9         1      22
5    03/03/2021 02/03/2021  12345   5         1      33
```

where `count` column is the number of the rows for the same `ID` & `as_of_date`, for example, for `as_of_date=02/03/2021` and `ID=12345`,there are two rows (each row has different `create_date` but I don't care about the `create_date`), so `count` for the first two rows are the same: 2.

The expected JSON is:

```
{
    "examples": [
        {
            "Id": 12345,
            "as_of_date": "2021-03-02 00:00:00", # this field is datetime format
            "value_3": 55, 
            "count": 2,    # for the same 'ID=12345'&'as_of_date=02/03/2021'
            "display_rows": [
                {
                    "value_1": 5,
                    "type": "int" # 'type' field will always be 'int'
                },
                {
                    "value_1": 8,
                    "type": "int"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 34567,
            "as_of_date": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
            "value_3": 66,
            "count": 1,
            "display_rows": [
                {
                    "value_1": 9,
                    "type": "int"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 78945,
            "as_of_date": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
            "value_3": 77,
            "count": 1,
            "display_rows": [
                {
                    "value_1": 9,
                    "type": "int" 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 78945,
            "as_of_date": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
            "value_3": 22,
            "count": 1,
            "display_rows": [
                {
                    "value_1": 9,
                    "type": "int" 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 12345,
            "as_of_date": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
            "value_3": 33,
            "count": 1,
            "display_rows": [
                {
                    "value_1": 5,
                    "type": "int" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It took me almost a whole day to figure out, but seems not working... Can someone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function for processing `value_1` column like:

```
import json

df['as_of_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['as_of_date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')


f = lambda x: [ {"value_1": y, "type": "int" } for y in x]
df = (df.groupby(['as_of_date','ID','value_3','count'])['value_1']
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(name='display_rows'))
print (df)
  as_of_date     ID  value_3  count  \
0 2021-03-02  12345       55      2   
1 2021-03-02  34567       66      1   
2 2021-03-02  78945       77      1   
3 2021-03-03  12345       33      1   
4 2021-03-03  78945       22      1   

                                        display_rows  
0  [{'value_1': 5, 'type': 'int'}, {'value_1': 8,...  
1                    [{'value_1': 9, 'type': 'int'}]  
2                    [{'value_1': 9, 'type': 'int'}]  
3                    [{'value_1': 5, 'type': 'int'}]  
4                    [{'value_1': 9, 'type': 'int'}]  

j = json.dumps({"examples":df.to_dict(orient='records')}, default=str)
```

---

```
print (j)
{"examples": [{"as_of_date": "2021-03-02 00:00:00", "ID": 12345, "value_3": 55, "count": 2, "display_rows": [{"value_1": 5, "type": "int"}, {"value_1": 8, "type": "int"}]}, {"as_of_date": "2021-03-02 00:00:00", "ID": 34567, "value_3": 66, "count": 1, "display_rows": [{"value_1": 9, "type": "int"}]}, {"as_of_date": "2021-03-02 00:00:00", "ID": 78945, "value_3": 77, "count": 1, "display_rows": [{"value_1": 9, "type": "int"}]}, {"as_of_date": "2021-03-03 00:00:00", "ID": 12345, "value_3": 33, "count": 1, "display_rows": [{"value_1": 5, "type": "int"}]}, {"as_of_date": "2021-03-03 00:00:00", "ID": 78945, "value_3": 22, "count": 1, "display_rows": [{"value_1": 9, "type": "int"}]}]}
```

EDIT:

```
#added some another column
df['value_7'] = 52
print (df)
   as_of_date create_date     ID  value_1  count  value_3  value_7
0  02/03/2021  02/03/2021  12345        5      2       55       52
1  02/03/2021  01/03/2021  12345        8      2       55       52
2  02/03/2021  01/03/2021  34567        9      1       66       52
3  02/03/2021  02/03/2021  78945        9      1       77       52
4  03/03/2021  02/03/2021  78945        9      1       22       52
5  03/03/2021  02/03/2021  12345        5      1       33       52

#added type column for last value in dict
df = (df.assign(type='int')
        .groupby(['as_of_date','ID','value_3','count'])[['value_1', 'value_7','type']]
        .apply(lambda x:  x.to_dict('records'))
        .reset_index(name='display_rows'))
print (df)
   as_of_date     ID  value_3  count  \
0  02/03/2021  12345       55      2   
1  02/03/2021  34567       66      1   
2  02/03/2021  78945       77      1   
3  03/03/2021  12345       33      1   
4  03/03/2021  78945       22      1   

                                        display_rows  
0  [{'value_1': 5, 'value_7': 52, 'type': 'int'},...  
1     [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'type': 'int'}]  
2     [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'type': 'int'}]  
3     [{'value_1': 5, 'value_7': 52, 'type': 'int'}]  
4     [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'type': 'int'}]  

j = json.dumps({"examples":df.to_dict(orient='records')}, default=str)
```

EDIT:

```
df = (df.assign(example_placeholder='xyz')
        .groupby(['as_of_date','ID','value_3','count'])[['value_1', 'value_7','example_placeholder']]
        .apply(lambda x:  x.to_dict('records'))
        .reset_index(name='display_rows'))
print (df)
   as_of_date     ID  value_3  count  \
0  02/03/2021  12345       55      2   
1  02/03/2021  34567       66      1   
2  02/03/2021  78945       77      1   
3  03/03/2021  12345       33      1   
4  03/03/2021  78945       22      1   

                                        display_rows  
0  [{'value_1': 5, 'value_7': 52, 'example_placeh...  
1  [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'example_placeh...  
2  [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'example_placeh...  
3  [{'value_1': 5, 'value_7': 52, 'example_placeh...  
4  [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'example_placeh...
```

---

```
df = (df.assign(aa='xyz', type='int')
        .groupby(['as_of_date','ID','value_3','count'])[['value_1', 'value_7','aa', 'type']]
        .apply(lambda x:  x.to_dict('records'))
        .reset_index(name='display_rows'))
print (df)

   as_of_date     ID  value_3  count  \
0  02/03/2021  12345       55      2   
1  02/03/2021  34567       66      1   
2  02/03/2021  78945       77      1   
3  03/03/2021  12345       33      1   
4  03/03/2021  78945       22      1   

                                        display_rows  
0  [{'value_1': 5, 'value_7': 52, 'aa': 'xyz', 't...  
1  [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'aa': 'xyz', 't...  
2  [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'aa': 'xyz', 't...  
3  [{'value_1': 5, 'value_7': 52, 'aa': 'xyz', 't...  
4  [{'value_1': 9, 'value_7': 52, 'aa': 'xyz', 't...
```

Comment: Hi thanks, just a quick follow-up question, what if I have multiple columns like `value_1` needs to be added in section `display_rows`? I tried:```df = (df.groupby(['as_of_date','ID','value_3','count'])['value_1', 'value_7', 'value_8']
        .apply(lambda x: [ {"value_1": a,'value_7' : b, 'value_8': c, "type": "int" } for a, b, c in x]) .reset_index(name='display_rows'))``` This gave me error `.apply(lambda x: [{
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: Thanks, it seems not working if I change `'type='int'` to some other strings, like `.assign(example_placeholder = 'xyz'`

Comment: @Cecilia - `example_placeholder ` is added after groupby  like `[['value_1', 'value_7','example_placeholder']]` ?

Comment: yes, in section `display_rows`, but the value for it is always the same string such as 'xyz', I tried the new code but `example_placeholder` is not in section `displacy_rows`

Comment: @Cecilia - interesting, add edit and for me working well.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael , just a minor thing, `to_dict(orient='records')` gave me a warning `FutureWarning: Using short name for 'orient' is deprecated. Only the options: ('dict', list, 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index') will be used in a future version. Use one of the above to silence this warning`, it seems still there if I use `to_dict('records')`

Comment: @Cecilia - It is weird, because if `to_dict(orient='r')` error has sense, here not understand, because `orient='records'` is in `('dict', list, 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index') `

Comment: I know the issue, I should use `records` instead of `record`, a silly mistake.

Comment: Just a follow-up question if that's ok, what if I want to save this output to a JSON file? I tried: `with open("your_json_file", "w") as fp: json.dump({"examples": dataframe.to_dict('records')}, fp)` but it gave me error `TypeError: Object of type Timestamp is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @Cecilia - one idea is convert datetimes to strigns like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404559/python-error-typeerror-object-of-type-timestamp-is-not-json-serializable) or use some solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Thanks, the 'conver to str' approach works, just wondering if there is a way I can save the json file in an object and write it to AWS s3 bucket? Can I just use the `j` object in this answer above?

Comment: @Cecilia - Never do it, so no idea. Maybe try looking for some ssolution or post question for this problem.